# Making change using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, coin-change

I just recently started studying Objective-C (or programming for that matter) and am stuck at a simple program.

I'm trying to create change in quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies but noticed that the solution I came up with would give random value to nickels or pennies.

Ex.
Change for 25 would come out to "The change is 1 quarter, 0 dime, -1881139893 nickels, and 4096 pennis"

Ex2.
Change for 30 would come out to "The change is 1 quarter, 0 dime, 1 nickels, and 4096 pennis"

What can I add/change to fix this behavior?

Also, is there any better solution then having to run 4 different if statements?

Thanks!

Here's my code below:

```
int orig, q, d, n, p;

NSLog(@"Give money to make change");
scanf("%i", &orig);

if(orig >= 25) {
    q = orig/25;
    orig -=  q*25;
}
if(orig >= 10 && orig < 25) {
    d = orig/10;
    orig -= d*10;
}
if(orig >= 5 && orig < 10) {
    n = orig/5;
    orig -= n*5;
}
if(orig >= 1 && orig < 5) {
    p = orig;
}

NSLog(@"The change is %i quarter, %i dime, %i nickels, and %i pennis", q, d, n, p);
```

Comment: `pennies`, by the way.  Not `pennis`.  =)

Answer (score 4):

You don't initialize your variables to start with, so they all start with random values, then in your code, in the case where there's no pennys, you never set p to anything, so it retains its initial random value, which you then see in your output. You can fix it by initializing your variables at the start.

```
int orig=0, q=0, d=0, n=0, p=0;
```

Comment: I see, I did realize that setting it's initial value to 0 helped the solution, however, it seems like DIME would always be 0 even if i didnt set an initial value? Will make sure to keep that in mind in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Hyung: it's not really random, it's what was in that memory location before.  If you call a function that just initializes a lot of local variables to (say) 42, and then returns, and _directly on return_ you call your change-making function, you'd likely see 42's for your number of dimes.

Comment: @Hyung Suh: As Aidan said, it's not random, but it's not reliable either. It's just *likely* to work that way on most computers. Just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

You should make use of modulus instead. I don't want to ruin your learning experience so this is an example of how you can use modulus to calculate days, hours, minutes and seconds for time given in seconds only.

```
int x = 1123123; 
int seconds = x % 60;
x /= 60;
int minutes = x % 60;
x /= 60;
int hours = x % 24;
x /= 24;
int days = x;
```

Now apply it to your problem :)

Comment: Will try that out. Thanks for the suggestion! Really helps to get pointers like this. :)